# Advice and optimization of the sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have three tables which have different data and columns are:

```
 | id | type | src | shop | sex | brand | label | price | sizes |
 |  1 | hat  |image| zara | man | zara  | -25%  | 1000  | s,m,l |
 ................................................................
 ................................................................
```

This is the first table, but there are also two tables, which are different only in types of the items, I mean: in the first table there are accessories, in the second there are clothes and in the third there are shoes...the equal columns are: id, sex, shop and that's all

I need to take 8 different items from accessories_table, 2 items from clothes_table and 1 item from shoes_table

Here is the query:

```
  SELECT src,type FROM `accs_w` WHERE type IN( 'hat', 'scarf', 'earnings', 'necklace', 
 'ring', 'purse', 'gloves','belt') GROUP BY type 
  UNION 
  SELECT src,type FROM clothes_w WHERE type IN('shirt','pants') GROUP BY type 
  UNION 
  SELECT src,type FROM shoes_w WHERE type='boots' GROUP BY type
```

It returns me this :

```
  //pi3.lmcdn.ru/img172x248/M/O/MO002HWKU687_1.jpg
  necklace
  //pi3.lmcdn.ru/img172x248/F/R/FR008HWIG495_1.jpg
  ring
  //pi0.lmcdn.ru/img172x248/R/E/RE770DWKZ609_1.jpg
  gloves
  //pi4.lmcdn.ru/img172x248/I/C/IC415BWIK986_1.jpg
  purse
  //pi4.lmcdn.ru/img172x248/P/I/PI752DWJK584_1.jpg
  belt
  //pi3.lmcdn.ru/img172x248/F/R/FR008HWIG653_1.jpg
  earnings
  //pi2.lmcdn.ru/img172x248/M/A/MA002CWJW087_1.jpg
  hat
  //pi3.lmcdn.ru/img172x248/C/A/CA003GWKV794_1.jpg
  scarf
  //pi4.lmcdn.ru/img172x248/M/A/MA015EWKZ264_1.jpg
  bra
  //pi4.lmcdn.ru/img172x248/C/A/CA105EWLM131_1.jpg
  pants
 //pi3.lmcdn.ru/img172x248/C/L/CL009AWIX318_1.jpg
 shoes
```

Question:

Is it okay to query in such a way? Is there another way to do it better?

Thank you!

Comment: This schema violates the [Principle of Orthogonal Design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_Orthogonal_Design).  Why not combine your tables into a single one, with a column that identifies the product type?

Comment: @eggyal I know that the quaries will be easier, but the table will be consist of 11k rows, is it okay? won't it be slow?

Comment: @CostaRassco: 11k records is *nothing* for a properly indexed table.  Even if you had hundreds of millions of records, where it might be sensible to divide the table up, you should use MySQL's native [partitioning](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/partitioning.html) rather than trying to hack it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One additional info: please try to replace all 'UNION' to 'UNION ALL'. As far as you know that all 'types' are unique between tables. But the main idea is to combine all of the stuff to one single table. Even if it would contain hundreds of millions of records it's better that supporting several tables with single structure (for example, during adding some new columns etc.).